# c++ predefined instances

Tags: c++

I am designing a Vector3D class and would like to have easy access to some often used vectors, such as the Cartesian basis vectors and the origo. Below is an approach that uses static members. Is this the correct way to achieve this? Performance will be a key point.

**vector.h**

```
#include <iostream>

class Vector3D {

public:
    Vector3D(double x=0.0, double y=0.0, double z=0.0) :
        x_(x),
        y_(y),
        z_(z) {};

    inline void print() const {
        std::cout << x_ << " " << y_ << " " << z_ << std::endl;
    }

    // Predefined Vectors
    static Vector3D ZERO;
    static Vector3D X;
    static Vector3D Y;
    static Vector3D Z;

    double x_, y_, z_;
};
```

**vector.cpp**

```
#include "vector.h"

// Predefined vectors
Vector3D Vector3D::ZERO = Vector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Vector3D Vector3D::X    = Vector3D(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Vector3D Vector3D::Y    = Vector3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
Vector3D Vector3D::Z    = Vector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

The class can then be used like this:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "vector.h"

int main()
{
    Vector3D o = Vector3D::ZERO;
    Vector3D x = Vector3D::X;
    Vector3D y = Vector3D::Y;
    Vector3D z = Vector3D::Z;

    o.print();
    x.print();
    y.print();
    z.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a good implementation, IMO

Answer (score 1):

You missing `const` identifiers. You don't want someone accidentally modify ZERO =)

Also you may use static methods:

```
struct Vector3D
{
  //...

  static Vector3D const & ZERO()
  {
     static Vector3D zero_(0,0,0);
     return zero_;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! An yes - of course it should be const (too speedy with the keyboard)

Comment: Yes, you could use a static member function, but what do you gain by doing that?

Comment: @PeteBecker in template class there is no need to define them in distinct translation unit (if you will do it in header, you would have multiple definition)

Comment: Seems like a bad tradeoff. A constant shouldn't be a function, and the reason for doing it is to maybe make it easier to build the library?

Comment: @PeteBecker tell Eigen deelopers about that http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a2e36721b4833498b713e94a7948c6a29.
Why constants could not be returned by functions? What wrong with it to be function? As I said before there are problems with using static member variables in template context. What to do with that? Use non-standart features like `__declspec(selectany)`?

Comment: C++ is not Eigen, and without a great deal more explanation, such an analogy is meaningless. Yes, you can write constants that way, but most C and C++ programmers find it counterintuitive.

Comment: @PeteBecker Eigen is just an example of widely used approch. You did not answer, what your suggestions for constants inside template classes? As for counterintuitive, I think that function, which returns immutable object is more intuitive than having immutable object by itself.

Comment: For constants inside template classes, just like anything else in a template class, just write its definition in the header.

Comment: @PeteBecker Okay, I thought that this will violate ODR, but I think that I missed something :) But are there other drawbacks of meyer's singletons but `counterintuitiveness`?

Answer (score 1):

> **Use const whenever possible - Scott Meyers**

Your code is fine and in addition you can use `const`

```
class Vector3D
{
    // ...
    static const Vector3D ZERO;
    static const Vector3D X;
    static const Vector3D Y;
    static const Vector3D Z;
};

const Vector3D Vector3D::ZERO = Vector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
const Vector3D Vector3D::X    = Vector3D(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
const Vector3D Vector3D::Y    = Vector3D(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
const Vector3D Vector3D::Z    = Vector3D(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

*(I'm not sure) `const` keyword can help compiler to do better optimizations.*

Comment: Do you prefer: "static const Vector3D ZERO;" or "static Vector3D const ZERO;"?

Comment: I think both of them are equal, I prefer first one.

Answer (score 0):

The first four lines of the main function should be pointers being assigned the address of the static member vectors.

see: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/ 
"Member variables of a class can be made static by using the static keyword. Static member variables only exist once in a program regardless of how many class objects are defined! One way to think about it is that all objects of a class share the static variables."

You may want to change the name of the class/file, vector is a standard library template class.